# Typescript keyof a class

Tags: typescript

I want to pass a class to a function and infer the keys of the class but it doesn't work:

```
class Foo {
  bar: string;
}

function foo<C>(comp: C, key: keyof C) {

}

foo(Foo, '') // expecting to get bar here, but I'm getting the prototype key
```

When I use it as a type, it works:

```
type Keys = keyof Foo;
```

What's the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FIrst of all you need to provide initializer for `bar` property.
Second of all, you are passing class constructor as an argument and expect second to be `bar`. It can be `bar` only if you provide an instance of `Foo` class. If you want to get `bar` you need to use [`InstanceType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) utility type, in other words, get keys from class instance instead of class constructor:

```js
class Foo {
  bar: string = ''
}
type AnyClass = new (...args: any[]) => any

function foo<C extends AnyClass>(comp: C, key: keyof InstanceType<C>) {

}

foo(Foo, 'bar') // ok
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
var Foo = class Foo { ... }
foo(/* new () => Foo */ Foo, /* 'prototype' */ ...)
```

because Foo is a class (i.e. a function) and not an instance of Foo class